# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint on a column I not set it to be

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

My database is SQL Server. I want to insert a duplicate key in `RequestId`, then come across this error.

**In addition**:My database is created by `Visual Studio Sql Server 2008 Server Project`

I'm sure there is no constraint in the table.

Neither a column is `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestPrize] (
    [RequestId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [PrizeId]   INT           NULL,
    [Verified]  BIT           NOT NULL,
    [Created]   SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

But when I insert a duplicate key of RequestId:

```
insert into [RequestPrize] (RequestId, PrizeId) values('138', 9)
```

error output :

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_RequestPrize'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RequestPrize'.

Then I try to drop this constraint,

```
ALTER TABLE [RequestPrize] DROP CONSTRAINT RequestId
```

error :

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   'RequestId' is not a constraint.
>   Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

**update:**
I really want to know where this `CONSTRAINT` come from.

Comment: You need to drop the **constraint** - not the column! `ALTER TABLE [RequestPrize] DROP CONSTRAINT PK_RequestPrize`

Comment: @marc_s Oh!You are right,but I have no idea where this `CONSTRAINT ` come from.I created this DB by `Visual Studio Sql Server 2008 Server Project`, was it who added the `CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: And a table **without** a proper primary key constraint is really not very useful to begin with.... so my suggestion would be: find a **real** primary key for your table and define it as such! If you don't have any column(s) that are unique and non-null all the time, use an `INT IDENTITY` as a surrogate primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without PK all works fine -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RequestPrize
(
    [RequestId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [PrizeId]   INT           NULL,
    [Verified]  BIT           NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [Created]   SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.RequestPrize (RequestId, PrizeId) 
VALUES (138, 9)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.RequestPrize (RequestId, PrizeId) 
VALUES (138, 9)
GO
```

So drop (if exist) your PK -

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.objects o
    WHERE o.type = 'PK'
        AND o.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.RequestPrize', 'U')
) ALTER TABLE dbo.RequestPrize DROP CONSTRAINT PK_RequestPrize
```

Comment: Yes,raw sql will excute perfect,but my situation is different.I think it because My database is created by `Visual Studio Sql Server 2008 Server Project`.The solution is provided by @marc_s in comments, but I really want to know where this CONSTRAINT come from.

Comment: Last query drop if exists PK on table `dbo.RequestPrize`.

Comment: This method is really good,I just see the comment, then to modify my post .I'm sorry not found your updates.But I really want to know where this `CONSTRAINT` come from.

Comment: @Mithril, sorry, but I don't know. Maybe VS auto-generated PK on your table.

Answer (score 0):

To drop a constraint you have to use the alias name for constraint you specified while creating "PK_RequestPrize".

By Syntax i guess you are using Microsoft SQLserver, to be sure check if query browser is connected to proper DB.

use "[dbo].[RequestPrize]" while inserting to have more confirmation.

[image]